# Breaking lineage of an RDD without relying on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I'm running a spark application on Amazon spot instances. In the end, I'm exporting my results to parquet files on S3. The tasks are memory intensive, so I have to run the initial calculations using a large number of partitions (hundreds of thousands). In the end, I would like to coalesce the partitions to a few large partitions and save them to big parquet files. And this is where I get into trouble:
- If I'm using `.coalesce()`, which is a narrow transformation, the entire lineage that precedes the coalesce will be executed on a small number of partitions, which will cause OOMs.
- If I'm using `.repartition()`, I rely on HDFS for the shuffle files. 
This is a problem when using spot instances, which may be decommissioned, leaving corrupt/missing HDFS blocks.
- checkpointing also relies on HDFS so I can't use that.
- converting to a `Dataframe` and back didn't actually break the lineage (`rdd.toDF.rdd`, am I missing something?).

To conclude, I'm looking for a way to coalesce to a smaller amount of partitions only to persist the data on S3 - I would like for the calculation to happen using the original partitions.

Comment: could you not persist and trigger computation with count or something and then coalesce after that?

Comment: Cannot say I follow your point. Shallow, they are narrow or wide.

Comment: @ag29 you're right, I forgot to persist for the lineage to break. This, however, didn't solve my original issue. Instead of relying on HDFS I now rely on distributed memory, which essentially keeps the same issues that prevent from long-running jobs to finish on spot instances (related read: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-running-apache-spark-applications-using-amazon-ec2-spot-instances-with-amazon-emr/).

Comment: To solve this I split the job to 2 separate jobs: First heavy lifting job that is ridiculously parallel (so no problem executing on spots), and a short one that merges the first output to big files (does involve shuffle, however on much lower volume, so it's very quick to finish).

Comment: @thebluephantom thanks, I edited the original post